# RegEx words match

Tags: ruby, regex, nokogiri

element on the page has needed content that i'm trying to pull
here's the `element.content` after a parse with Nokogiri

```
["\n       \n       \n       \n          itemId[0]=1234;\n       \n        \n          \n        \n       \n       \n       \n        My Project: First Edition\n       \n      ", "\n       \n       \n       \n          itemId[1]=2345;\n       \n        \n          \n        \n       \n       \n       \n        My Second Edition\n       \n      ", "\n       \n       \n       \n          itemId[2]=1234;\n       \n        \n          \n        \n       \n       \n       \n        Third\n       \n          \n"]
```

I was able to get the RegEx for the `itemId[0]=1234` which is `(/itemId.\d+..\d{4}/)` but I'm totally stuck on how to grab the names of the content. Any advice? Perhaps I can just parse with Ruby through HTML?

Comment: i was able to parse an element differently; I separate the itemId and Name from a single parse; and I was able to get the needed information. Helps to do things rights from the get to. Thanks all !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a string like this:

```
s= "\n       \n       \n       \n          itemId[0]=1234;\n       \n        \n          \n        \n       \n       \n       \n        My Project: First Edition\n       \n      "
```

You could do this:

```
m    = s.match(/(itemId\[\d+\]=\d+);(.*)/m)
item = m[1]
# itemId[0]=1234
name = m[2].strip
# My Project: First Edition
```

Basically you pull out the `itemId...` part using (more or less) or existing expression, grab the rest of the string (`(.*)`) in multi-line mode (`/m`, so that `.` matches a newline), and then strip off the offending whitespace outside the regex using [`strip`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-strip). You don't have to build one unreadable regex that does everything you need, post-processing a match result is allowed and sometimes even encouraged.

Comment: seems that the item = m[1] take the first (itemId\[\d+\]=\d+) while the name = m[2] take the rest of the string and stops there... mmmm

Comment: @ZeTradr: So just apply it to each element in your array. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use `split` to find all non-empty lines.

```
str.split(/\s*\n\s*/)
```

should do the trick.